# how to show multiple marker on google map android

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps-android-api-2

i want to show location with multiple markers on google maps android, the problem is when i run my apps, it just show one location/marker, this is my code :

```
public class koordinatTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
             String url = "http://absc?action=p04&prov="+link_kode+"&tipe=";
             JSONArray data = null;
            try {
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                // Getting Array of data
                data = json.getJSONArray(real_data);
                System.out.println("realisasi done");

                for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    HashMap<String, Double> map1 = new HashMap<String, Double>();
                    x_lat = c.getDouble(x_cord);
                    y_long = c.getDouble(y_cord);
                    label = c.getString(prov_label);
                    map1.put(x_cord, x_lat);
                    map1.put(y_cord, y_long);
                    map.put(prov_label, label);
                    ProvinsiList.add(map);
                    ProvinsiList.add(map1);
                    System.out.println(x_lat);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            LatLng MAP_PUPI = new LatLng(x_lat, y_long);
            Marker Pupi = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(x_lat, y_long)).title(label));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MAP_PUPI, 15));

            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
        }   
    }
```

i don't know where's my fault, i hope somebody can help me to solve my problem, thank u verymuch