# how to add multiple marker on google map in android app

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a problem about add multiple markers on Google Maps in my app from array-list of its getting values from database

when I write this code I get only one marker which is last address of array but I want all address in my map with mark.

```
package com.example.rajkot_tourism;

import handler.handler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import property.property;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class mainmap extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
{

    ArrayList arlat=new ArrayList();
    ArrayList arlang=new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> arname=new ArrayList<String>();
    private GoogleMap googlemap;
    private LocationManager loc;
    private MarkerOptions marker;
    double lng;
    double lat;
    String name;

    String name1;
    double lat1;
    double lng1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_map);

        googlemap=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        int idc=b.getInt("idc");

        handler h=new handler(mainmap.this);
        ArrayList<property> p=h.cat_map(idc);

        for(property p1 : p)
    {

            double lat1=p1.getPlace_latitude();
            double lng1=p1.getPlace_longitude();
            String placename=p1.getPlace_name();
            arname.add(placename);
            arlat.add(lat1);
            arlang.add(lng1);
    }
        Criteria criteria=new Criteria();
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        loc=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        String  provider=loc.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Location location=loc.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


        updatewithnewlocation(location);

    }



        LocationListener loclist=new LocationListener() {

@Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


    }

@Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

@Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


    }

@Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Toast.makeText(mainmap.this,"Location Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    };

        String lastloc;

        private void updatewithnewlocation(Location location) {

//      for(int i=0;i<arname.size();i++)
//      
//  {
            name=arname.get(0);
            lat=(Double) arlat.get(0);
            lng=(Double) arlang.get(0);

            marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title(name);

            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
            googlemap.addMarker(marker);

    //}

            name1=arname.get(1);
            lat1=(Double) arlat.get(1);
            lng1=(Double) arlang.get(1);

            MarkerOptions marker1 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat1, lng1)).title(name1);

            marker1.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
            googlemap.addMarker(marker1);


    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972476/how-to-show-multiple-marker-on-google-map-android

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop when you're adding all your markers, you're getting the same value each time rather than looping through using your variable i. This is what you're doing when you're getting the values:

```
arname.get(0);
```

You need to do:

```
arname.get(i);
```